# Angular 6 - how to go to another view by clicking the icon?

Tags: angular6

i dont have the idea how to do it. please can you give me an idea on how to go to another view by clicking the icon on the Angular6? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To change view in Angular(without reloading page), **you need Routers.**

You can wrap your icon inside an anchor tag `<a>` and use `routerLink` to define the view you want to load when a user clicks on the icon.

**For example**, you are building an e-commerce site where you have an icon for contacts and one for a shopping cart. You can define view for each icon like this:

```
<a routerLink="/contacts" routerLinkActive="active">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>contacts</mat-icon>
</a>
<a routerLink="/shopping_cart" routerLinkActive="active">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
</a>
```

So when the user clicks on `contacts icon`, contactsComponent will be loaded in your view and the URL would change to `yourwebsite.com/contacts`.

You can learn more about [routers](https://angular.io/guide/router) and [material-icon](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline).